# nested query not running, always returns null.

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have am working on a mobile app, when a user logs in against a php/mysql webserver the users details are stored in the local sqlite db via json.

This works fine. Next, I am trying to have a second sqlite table update from another table in the mysql DB.

The returned json is always null for the second query. (the query is fine if run alone)

Can I run two queries like this ?? Any ideas ?

Thanks.

```
<?php

include 'DB_Connect.php';


    // get tag
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
    $tag = 'login';

    //json response array
    $response = array();

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //check user exists
    $qry = "SELECT uid, name, email, registration_date, updated_at FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? ";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($uid, $name, $email, $registration_date, $updated_at); // get variables from result.
    $stmt->fetch();
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){

            // if user exists, set json values
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $uid;
            $response["user"]["name"] = $name;
            $response["user"]["email"] = $email;
        $response["user"]["registration_date"] = $registration_date;
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $updated_at;
            echo json_encode($response);
            $stmt->close();

        if  ($response["success"] = 1 ){
            $qry = "SELECT device_name, device_registration_date FROM devices WHERE parent_id =?";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$uid);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($device_name, $device_registration_date); // get variables from result.
            $stmt->fetch();
            $response2["device"]["device_name"] = $device_name;
            $response2["device"]["device_registration_date"] = $device_registration_date;
            echo json_encode($response2);
            }

  else if ($tag = 'register' ... blah blah blah .....
```

Comment: How are you reading the response from PHP? It doesn't usually work to send multiple JSON responses in the same request.

Comment: Why are you doing two queries, anyway? Do a single query with a LEFT JOIN, to get both results at once.

Comment: ahh , of course ... works now :-) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query both tables at once with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.email, u.registration_date, u.updated_at,
       d.device_name, d.device_registration_date
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN devices d ON d.parent_id = u.uid
WHERE u.email = ? and u.password = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this solves the problem:

```
if ($response["success"] = 1 ){
```

should be:

```
if ($response["success"] == 1 ){
```

(two equals in an if)